# 'iostream' file not found

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation, compiler-errors

I have the following folders inside `/usr/include/c++`:

```
4.6
4.7
4.8
4.9
```

I want to run a program but that program gives me an error while it uses 4.6. I want it to use 4.9, therefore, I removed 4.6. Now I am getting this error:

```
'iostream' file not found
```

How do I fix this? How do I use 4.9? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: How about `g++-4.9`?

Comment: I am using g++4.9. But the problem is that I am working on OpenCL. Now in the cl.hpp file, there is a line that says: `#include <atomic>`. Due to this, the file is being searched in `usr/include/c++/4.6`. But I want it to search in `usr/include/c++/4.9`.

Comment: If you explicitly use the version 4.9 of GCC, then C++ system header files should be looked for in the 4.9 directory. Or else your system is misconfigured.

Comment: Any good tutorial for removing all gcc/g++/c++ related stuff and then re installing only the new versions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding

```
export CPATH=/usr/include/c++/4.9:$CPATH
```

in your ~/.bashrc file?

because I think this might be a problem with your include path not containing your /usr/include/c++/4.9 folder